# Asking for License to assign a permission set to a user in test class

Tags: code-coverage, failing-tests, apextestrunresult

Hi all i am assigning a permission set to a user below the code

"

```
public static void assignPermissionSetsToUser(Id userId, Set<String> permissionSets) {
        List<PermissionSetAssignment> psaList;
        if(userId!=null && permissionSets != null && !permissionSets.isEmpty()){
            psaList = new List<PermissionSetAssignment>();
            for(PermissionSet psObj : [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE IsOwnedByProfile = FALSE and Name in :permissionSets]){
                PermissionSetAssignment psaObj = new PermissionSetAssignment(PermissionSetId = psObj.Id, AssigneeId = userId);
                psaList.add(psaObj);
            }
        }
        INSERT psaList;
    }"
```

[image]

Comment: the profile is Standard User profile and in Org the users with this profiles have permission set assigned

Answer (score 0):

This question has little ambiguity. What type of profile do the user have. Also the error do not show which permission is causing the problem.

I will suggest couple of things.

1. Check the debug logs to find more details of permission which is preventing Permission Set assignment.
2. Other simple option can be try assigning permission set manually.

This will help you understand which permission is causing problem and from there it can be taken forward.